# Google Cloud Storage: storage.delete(BlobId blobId) method generates NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to delete an image uploaded on the Cloud Storage. I imported Cloud Storage dependencies from Maven as written in the documentations, and I have no problem with uploading a file to the Cloud through Java.

Here is my method for deleting the image:

```
public static void removeImage(String imageName) {

        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
        BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, imageName);
        boolean deleted = storage.delete(blobId); //Debugging the code here it generates the error
        if (deleted) System.out.println("Object " + imageName + " was deleted from " + bucketName);
        else System.out.println("Something went wrong");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing a clean install of Maven (mvn clean install), i think there were some dependencies that were in conflict and caused the error